# & symbol in C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++

there.  I am confused about what the use of the & symbol between the classname and variable name in a c++ #define statement.

I found it in the globalhandling.hpp file in the xbmc source code to create a global singleton.

I wrote a similar version of the snippet to figure out what it does.  What I found when experimenting with it is when & is used only one constructor and destructor is called.  If I omit it one constructor and two destructors is called.

Is & acting as a bitwise and or an address operator in this context?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class aClass
{
  public:

    aClass() { cout << "Constructor\n"; }


    aClass getInstance() { return *this; }

    void printMessage() { cout << "Hello\n"; }

    ~aClass() { cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};

#define GLOBAL_REF(classname,variable) \
    static boost::shared_ptr<classname> variable##Ref(new classname)

#define GLOBAL(classname,variable) \
    GLOBAL_REF(classname,variable); \
    static classname & variable = (*(variable##Ref.get()))


GLOBAL(aClass,aVariable);

int main()
{   
    aVariable.printMessage();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the PP. It's a plain old reference.

Comment: You're creating the reference.

Comment: Why when omitting the `&` does two destructors get called.

Comment: Uhm, a **macro** to create a **global** object that is **dynamically allocated** and **reassignable**, with **token-paste**-generated name and a reference that can become **unsynchronized** with the pointer. Someone's gone overboard with this. So much worst practice in one go.

Comment: One should understand preprocessor first.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` symbol you're referring to is presumably this one:

```
static classname & variable = (*(variable##Ref.get()))
```

In which case the ampersand isn't anything to do with the C preprocessor, it is in fact the C++ [reference symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

You would typically use it to refer to an already declared object, similar to a pointer.

For example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
int &c = a;

// a = 1, b = 1, c = 1.

b = 2;   

// a = 1, b = 2, c = 1.

a = 3;

// a = 3, b = 2, c = 3. Note that variable 'c', which is a reference to 'a', has also changed.

c = 4;

// a = 4, b = 2, c = 4.
```

Comment: I found out omitting & copies the object rather referencing it.  I added a copy constructor to `aClass` to confirm that.